# Connect to MySQL through SSH and by using Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, ssh

In my `Spring Boot`app WAR, I have an `application.properties` file wherein I have defined following `datasource` properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
spring.datasource.username=used
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

with this, I am able to connect to the database.

Now, I want to connect to another database through `SSH tunnel`. How should I specify `spring.datasource.url` to get such connection?

Please note I don't want to write any boiler plate Java code to do this SSH tunneling!

*P.S. I Googled but could not find satisfactory answer anywhere.*

Answer (score 12):

I don't think spring can create a SSH tunnel for you if that's what you're looking for. If you want to do it in the code, you need a framework like jsch.

The best solution would be to create the SSH tunnel on the server manually or by using autossh (to keep it up).
To create a tunnel manually, log on to your app server and run this command in a screen:

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 serverIp
```

3306 is the port mysql is running on. 3307 is the port you are forwarding.
With this tunnel you can now connect by using:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/
```

Answer (score 6):

same problem with me.

my solution resolved,

**Step 1:** create **ec2 instance** inside VPC **public subnet**

**Step 2:** in the **security groups** this ec2 instance must be allow port 22 (SSH)

**Step 3:** RDS MySQL must be allow private-ip for **ec2 instance** to access

**Step 4:** In Dev Local ~> setup forward listener tcp_ip **open terminal**

```
ssh -f <user>@<ec2-public-dns> -L <localhost_ip>:<localhost_port>:<rds_mysql_host_ip>:<rds_mysql_host_port> -N -i <private_key>.pem
```

Example:

```
ssh -f ec2-user@ec2-public-dns -L dev-mysql-c-lib.internal:3306:***.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -N -i ~/.ssh/ec2-instance.pem
```

[image]

**Step 5:** in file config application-dev.yml

changed host from **public-dns** to **internal-dns**

Example:

**host:** '***.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com'

to

**host:** 'dev-mysql-c-lib.internal'

spring.datasource.url: **jdbc:mysql://dev-mysql-c-lib.internal:3306/mydb**

Finally to Running Spring Boot

Lookup MySQL **Connected**

Work for me. ^____^

Comment: Thank you it worked for me as well, I just have MySQL running locally so I used another port for forwarding :      

ssh -N -L 3307:mysql-hostname:3306 ssh-user@ssh-server

Answer (score -3):

The same as you used in your question except useSSL=true and possibly verifyServerCertificate=false if your database uses self-signed certificate.

Comment: Oh, I asked about SSH configuration